# MATLAB Computer Vision Toolbox's equivalent functions of Image Processing Toolbox

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have tried to find punched and non-punched objects in a binary image. [image: binary image]

I have written a code which utilizes bwlabel function to detect whether object is punched or not.

```
close all; 
clear all;
clc;

I = imread('img1.jpg');

level = graythresh(I);

I2 = im2bw(I, level);

%Get object count
[L, NUM] = bwlabel(I2, 8);

punchedObj = 0;

disp(sprintf('%d objects detected.\n',NUM));

for i=1:NUM
    r = changem(L==i, 1, i);

    r2 = imcomplement(r);

    [rL rNUM] = bwlabel(r2,8);

    if rNUM > 1
        punchedObj = punchedObj + 1; 
    end         
end

disp(sprintf('%d of objects are punched and remaining %d are solid.',...
    punchedObj, NUM-punchedObj));

imshow(I);
```

> 27 objects detected.
>
> 6 of objects are punched and remaining 21 are solid.

This code works well. But I want to do the same work using Computer Vision Toolbox of MATLAB rather than Image Processing Toolbox.

Comment: What's the reason for your Toolbox selection?

Comment: vision.ConnectedComponentLabeler is the corresponding object for bwlabel in Computer Vision System toolbox. What is the reason for switching? bwlabel also generates code if you are looking for that feature.

Comment: Very rarely does one only want to use the computer vision toolbox and not the image processing toolbox.  They go hand in hand.  What's the reason for the migration?